# How to achieve hittest behavior in WriteableBitmap

Tags: .net, wpf, writeablebitmap

I have a image `(System.Windows.Controls)` *class*. I have given **WriteableBitmap** to image source and drawn line in image. I need to show the *tooltip* on the line when *mouse ove*r the line region. How can I achieve this?